# serialize children in marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Marshmallow normally serializes nested children (assuming nested schema are defined). For example:

```
{
    'id': 2,
    'messages' : [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'message': 'foo'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'message': 'bar'
        }
      ]
}
```

However, marshmallow-sqlalchemy causes children to simply be represented by their primary key. For example:

```
{
    'id': 2,
    'messages' : [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

How can I get marshmallow-sqlalchemy to serialize the child objects. Preferably, I should be able to specify a depth. For example: serialize to 4 layers deep, then use the uid behavior.

Ideally, this should be configurable via `schema.load()` because it should be dynamic based on where the serialization began. In other words, coupling this to the schema itself doesn't make sense. However, if that's the only way to do it, I'm curious to hear a solution like that as well.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use for your second example? Do you just use the `class Meta`?

Answer (score 1):

You can used a Nested field to do this.

Assuming you have a schema that looks like this:

```py
class MessageSchema(Schema):
    msg_id = fields.Integer()
    message = fields.String()
    something = fields.String()

class ListSchema(Schema):
    list_id = fields.Integer()
    messages = fields.Nested(MessageSchema, only=['msg_id', 'message'])
```

To include only certain fields, use the `only` parameter when calling `Nested` (see example above for usage, where only `msg_id` and `message` fields are included in the serialized output).

The [Marshmallow docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/nesting.html) have a more detailed + complete example: